# How to build array contains conditional

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to build a window listener that triggers on the **`mouseover`** on a box using **`contains`** and I'm not quite sure of how to build that?

[This](https://codepen.io/queflojera/pen/zYYPmEY?editors=1010) is a test I've built:

```
window.addEventListener("mouseover", trial)

function trial(e) {
  const contain_material = document.getElementsByClassName("item")
  if(contain_material.contains(e.target)) {
    alert("so far so good")
  }
  else {
    return
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

See if the following works for you.

```
function trial(e) {
  const contain_material = document.getElementsByClassName("item")
  for (var i = 0; i < contain_material.length; i++) {
    if(contain_material[i] == e.target) {
      alert("so far so good")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking hover on the window, why not just check when one of those elements is hovered over. For example:

```
const contain_material = document.getElementsByClassName("item")
for (mat of contain_material) {
  mat.addEventListener("mouseover", trial)
}
function trial(e) {
  alert("so far so good")  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just listen to the mouseover on the box element instead of in the whole page?

```js
function handleMouseOver() {
  alert('so far so good')
}

// or you can add dynamicaly with js

var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
Array.from(boxes).forEach(function() {
  this.onmouseover = () => alert('so far so good')
})

// () => this is an arrow function in case you dont know
// Array.from() is because you can't use the forEach straight with a HTMLCollection
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="item" onmouseover="handleMouseOver()"></div>
  <div class="item" onmouseover="handleMouseOver()"></div>
  <div class="item" onmouseover="handleMouseOver()"></div>
  <div class="item" onmouseover="handleMouseOver()"></div>
</body>

</html>
```